# wpdb prepare doesn't replace the variables on the sql query string

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Trying to add some data on the database but I cannot make the `prepare` works.

This is the code:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $products ); $i++ ) {
        $name = $products[$i]['Name'];
        $sku = $products[$i]['No'];
        $attr1 = $products[$i]['Attributes3'];
        $attr2 = $products[$i]['Attributes4'];
        $price = $products[$i]['Price'];    
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}products (name,sku,attribute1,attribute2,price) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', %f) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='%s', attribute1='%s', attribute2='%s', price=%f",
            mysql_real_escape_string($name),
            mysql_real_escape_string($sku),
            mysql_real_escape_string($attr1),
            mysql_real_escape_string($attr2),
            $price,
            mysql_real_escape_string($name),
            mysql_real_escape_string($attr1),
            mysql_real_escape_string($attr2),
            $price  
        );
        var_dump($sql);
        $wpdb->query($sql);
    }
```

I checked and the variables `$name`, `$sku` etc are not null, but the query string that is printed is this one:

```
string(160) "INSERT INTO wp_products (name,sku,attribute1,attribute2,price) VALUES ('', '', '', '', 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='', attribute1='', attribute2='', price=0"
```

I need the function `mysql_real_escape_string` because several rows contain single quotes.

Any idea why the query string doesn't replace the variables?

Edit: `mysql_real_escape_string` output. When I `var_dump` the variable `$name`, this is an example of the output: `string(25) "60's Jacket Blue"` and the `mysql_real_escape_string` returns `bool(false)`

But I cannot understand why it fails.

Comment: Reading [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php): `Returns the escaped string, or FALSE on error.`, check if your strings are actually strings or arrays/objects

Comment: can you please check my updated question?

Comment: Reading [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php#refsect1-function.mysql-real-escape-string-errors): `Executing this function without a MySQL connection present will also emit E_WARNING level PHP errors. Only execute this function with a valid MySQL connection present.`

Comment: If you cannot be sure about your connection, use [THIS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php#101248)